# Whenever I pull down my ASP.NET Web API repository, VSCode intellisense reports errors, why?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code

I can create an asp.net core solutions and projects just fine. There are no issues. However as soon as I push it up to github and then pull it down on my personal computer, VSCode intellisense reports problems and errors. However, I can run my rest api just fine. What is the problem?

For example if you try to clone `https://github.com/omikolaj/movies-place-api` this repository.

Here is an example:

[image]

I have tried deleting the entire project and starting from scratch. Same thing keeps happening. Same errors. This only happens on the PC in which I clone the repo. It does not happen on the PC where I created the asp.net rest api.

UPDATE
I ended up restarting visual studio code and it works.

Comment: There could be many reasons, however, the one I think it's the most likely: the errors are due to the missing package restore (which is done automatically by default when you build)

Comment: dotnet build successfully restores packages

Answer (score 0):

Restarting visual studio code ended up solving the issue.